# Where to validate arguments of a function and whether to throw or return?

Tags: javascript

I have few specific questions regarding function usage.

My apologies if it seems too basic to ask here. I am working on an ever growing project. These questions have been bothering me a lot lately.

**Questions:**

**1. Do I need to validate arguments in every single function?**

```
   //getConcatInfo: ("John Doe", 50, {name: "London"}) => "John 50 London"
    getConcatInfo(name, age, city){
        let first = name.split(" ")[0];
        return first + " " + age + " " + city.cityName;
    }
```

1. Should I check if each argument exists or not in every single function that I have in my project?
2. Should I check if each argument is the right type or not, for all functions? For example `city` should be an object with key `cityName` and `name` and `age` should be `String` and `Number`
3. If, say, two arguments exist and third doesn't should I throw an exception or just return null. **The reason for asking this is, libraries like `RXJS`, will stop listening to a given event the moment any error is thrown inside that event handler**

**2. Do I need to validate argument before calling a function?**

```
let name = user.name;
let name = user.age;
let city = getUserCity();

if(name && age && city && city.name) //<= like this?
   getConcatInfo(name, age, city);
```

My question is: **Do I go by approach 1 or 2 or both?**

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** trust input. You should check your arguments inside the function.

You have control over the function but no control over the calling sites.

Regarding how much checks you should do. This depends on your use case. Too few checks and you may end up with a lot of runtime problems, too much checks and you'll ship a lot slower, so it is up to you to figure out what is too much. A rule of thumb you can apply is that the more control you have over the calling sites less checks you can do inside the functions, but you **should not** trust input.

Returning null (or another value) or throwing an exception depends on how big the violation you get in your params. You can try to recover from minor problems: by returning null or using a default value for the specific param and execute your code. If you cannot recover from the error then you **should** throw an exception. In your case you could do something like this

```
getConcatInfo(name, age, city){
    name = name || 'default name'
    age = age || 18
    city = city || {cityName: 'default name'}
    let first = name.split(" ")[0];
    return first + " " + age + " " + city.cityName;
}
```

you could also use default params

```
getConcatInfo(name = 'default name', age = 18, city = {cityName: 'default name'}){
    let first = name.split(" ")[0];
    return first + " " + age + " " + city.cityName;
}
```

If you want type check you may want to look into [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org). But of course, this is a different language:)

Comment: Hey. Thanks. Could you please go  through the other parts of the questions as well?

Comment: By "don't trust input" I'm guessing you primarily mean input that came from the user (or other potentially-unreliable source)?

Comment: Primarily yes, but even input that comes from your own code shouldn't be trusted. Let's say you call all your method with the correct input and structure, but later on you add another call that doesn't conform to the desired structure.

Comment: Fair enough. TypeScript is a huge help in ensuring your app keeps data in the expected structure (by catching many structural errors at compile time not runtime).

Comment: Thanks! Your answer gives me a structure to think. Now every time, I will write a function, I will ask myself, whether to throw an error or return default values when arguments are invalid.

Comment: But you didn't cover calling a function. Should I have argument check at function call or not? Would be great if you could advice on this too.

Comment: Also, would be really really thankful if you could point me to some link related to this. If I google on this topic, all I get is recommendation on how to name function, number of arguments must be less than 4 etc.

Comment: My recommendation is to check your input. This should cover you. When calling getConcatInfo, you are in another method and should check your input in there. If the input and the rest of the computation is ok you should be able to safely call your method in there as your objects should be properly structured at this point.

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services If you are using typescript, you don't need to write checks for the existence and type of arguments, the compiler already does that. You only need to check for invalid values.

Comment: @Bergi Typescript only does compile time checking. But we are talking about run time issues here.

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services well you shouldn't check anything at runtime that was checked at compile time already, that just makes your code more complicated. Isn't this what you were asking about?

Comment: Hey @Bergi sorry but I don't understand your point. If my code is 100% type checked with TS, do you mean I shouldn't have any argument validation at all?

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services Not for the existence and type of parameters at least, yes.

Comment: I totally agree with @bergi. That's why you have a static typed language. You still need to take care of type consistency, which you do thru constructors and mutators. Making sure that each object is in a consistent state, but you don't need to do type checking anymore.